# clang-format still formatting with `DisableFormat: true`

Tags: clang-format

As [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) states:

> DisableFormat (bool): Disables formatting completely.

But checking a source `C++` file with having only this option in `.clang-format` still reports that the file needs formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently (at least with `clang-format 8.0`) `DisableFormat: true` does not override `SortIncludes` option, so that it also needs to be specified explicitly.  Having the following in `.clang-format` will disable formatting completely:

```
DisableFormat: true
SortIncludes: false
```

*UPDATE 1*

There's also an [issue report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35099) for Version 5.0 that hasn't got any attention up to now.

*UPDATE 2*

The issue is [fixed](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35099) in Version 13.0.